# JSON data alerting undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I retrieve this JSON via AJAX:

```
[{
    "tid": "1",
    "itemID": "Camry",
    "item_type": "Carf",
    "vendor_id": "ogbueli"
}, {
    "tid": "2",
    "itemID": "Samsung",
    "item_type": "Electronics",
    "vendor_id": "Chizoba"
}, {
    "tid": "3",
    "itemID": "Panasonic",
    "item_type": "Electronics",
    "vendor_id": "Mourinho"
}]
```

I have already parsed it:

```
arr = JSON.parse(response);
```

Now I want to access it like this:

```
for (var i in arr){
    newitems = arr[0];
    alert(newitems);
}
```

The alert is returning `undefined`. I want to get something like this:

```
newitems = { '1', 'camry', 'carf', 'ogbueli' };
```

Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: did you try `response[0]`?

Comment: `newitems = { '1', 'camry', 'carf', 'ogbueli' };` it is not a valid js object.

Comment: @madalinivascu is that necessary? since i have already parsed the response

Comment: Depending on how you retrieve the JSON, you may not need to parse it at all.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan could you direct me to any resource where i can read more about what you just said pls

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```js
var arr = [{"tid":"1","itemID":"Camry","item_type":"Carf","vendor_id":"ogbueli"},{"tid":"2","itemID":"Samsung","item_type":"Electronics","vendor_id":"Chizoba"},{"tid":"3","itemID":"Panasonic","item_type":"Electronics","vendor_id":"Mourinho"}];


var newitems = [], item;

for(var i in arr){
 
  // get item
  item = [arr[i].tid, arr[i].itemID, arr[i].item_type, arr[i].vendor_id];
  
  // push it to newitems array
  newitems.push(item);
  
}

alert(newitems[0]);
alert(newitems[1]);
alert(newitems[2]);
```

Comment: the length of 'newitems' continues to increase. thats not workable. it should be constant

Comment: I edited the code and do not understand what do you mean, if you say that the length of "newitems" increases? Could you please specify what is the end result you are looking for then.

Comment: i need something like this           newitems[0] = { '1', 'camry', 'carf', 'ogbueli' };    newitems[1]= { '2', 'samsung', 'electronics', 'chizoba' };

Comment: Edited the post one more time. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```js
a = [{"tid":"1","itemID":"Camry","item_type":"Carf","vendor_id":"ogbueli"},{"tid":"2","itemID":"Samsung","item_type":"Electronics","vendor_id":"Chizoba"},{"tid":"3","itemID":"Panasonic","item_type":"Electronics","vendor_id":"Mourinho"}];

for(i=0; i < a.length; i++){
  var val = a[i];
  newitems = [val.tid, val.itemID, val.item_type, val.vendor_id];
  alert(JSON.stringify(newitems));
}
```

Comment: does this mean i dont need to parse the response again?

Comment: @ordinaryman I dont think there is no need to parse it again, as per your input.

Comment: @ordinaryman you cannot get `{ '1', 'camry', 'carf', 'ogbueli' };` this, bout you can get `['1', 'camry', 'carf', 'ogbueli']`